# Sharing XML processing code between client and server in GWT

Tags: xml, gwt

I have a certain data structure that is shared between the client and the server parts in a GWT application. I need to be able to serialize/deserialize this data structure both on the server and on the client.

The data structure is relatively complex, so I would like to avoid duplicating the processing logic, i.e. I would like to use the same code to serialize/deserialize this data on the client and on the server.

If I use XML, is there any straightforward way to share the XML processing logic between the client and the server? The client XML classes do not implement any of the standard Java XML interfaces. Is there a more generic interface that can be used both on the client and on the server?

Comment: Try narrowing down your question to what you intend when you mean processing XML.

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to state the answer is NO.

GWT XML processing is documented here - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics#DevGuideXML

The above reference describes how you can consume XML data provide by server on Client side in GWT in best way. You must keep in mind if you try to **share** server side processing logic to client side it would be too heavy in peformance and will not scale well ( especially in complex data )